# SendGrid NuGet Package Installation Error

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, azure-mobile-services, nuget-package, sendgrid

Hi guys so I've updated the NuGet package manager to the latest version is Visual Studio 2013. The problem I'm having is trying to install the SendGrid NuGet package to my mobile service web API. The error I am getting when i try to install the package is shown below.
[image]

I've tried updating the Json.Net nuget package separately but this still doesn't work.
Is there any way to solve this issue or will i have to use an alternative to SendGrid

Comment: Could you please explain how you created your project in Visual Studio (e.g. what project template you used) so that I can try to replicate?

Answer (score 2):

The server packages for Mobile Services are very restrictive - in this particular case they constrain JSON.NET to version 6.0.4, but you are attempting to install a package that requires JSON.NET 7.0.1, hence the error.

Unfortunately I am not aware of a good workaround if you stay on Mobile Services.

The best solution is to move to using [Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-value-prop/). You can think of this as the new version of Mobile Services. The server packages for Azure Mobile Apps do not have the version restrictions you are running into here.